# Unir dos consultas - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Tengo las siguiente consultas:

```
SELECT linea, COUNT(falla) AS TotalFallas
    FROM sisma.registroproblemaaoi A
        WHERE fecha='2019-10-01' AND hora >='6:40' AND hora <='16:10' 
GROUP BY linea
```

Que me imprime los siguientes resultados:

> Linea......| TotalFallas 
>  Linea 01 | 1 
>  Linea 02 | 1 
>   Linea 06 | 6

Así mismo tengo esta otra:

```
SELECT psb_line, SUM(psb_produc) AS produccion 
    FROM psb_smt.psb_produccion
        WHERE DateTime >= '2019-10-01 6:40:00' AND DateTime <= '2019-10-01 16:10:00'
GROUP BY psb_line
```

Que muestra lo siguiente:

> Linea......| Produccion 
>  Linea 01 | 25 
>  Linea 06 | 511

La pregunta es ¿Cómo pueda relacionar ambas tablas de forma en que se agrupen por linea? Por ejemplo:

> Linea......| Produccion |TotalFallas 
>  Linea 01 | .......25.......
>   | 1
>  Linea 06 | .......511..... | 6

Espero su respuesta, saludos!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que no te deje ningún registro por fuera cuando exista algún valor de línea en una tabla y no esté en la otra, lo correcto sería esto:

```
SELECT linea, SUM(Produccion) AS Produccion, SUM(TotalFallas) AS TotalFallas
FROM (

    SELECT linea, 0 AS Produccion, COUNT(falla) AS TotalFallas
        FROM sisma.registroproblemaaoi A
            WHERE fecha='2019-10-01' AND hora >='6:40' AND hora <='16:10' 
    GROUP BY linea

    UNION

    SELECT psb_line, SUM(psb_produc) AS produccion, 0 AS TotalFallas 
        FROM psb_smt.psb_produccion
            WHERE DateTime >= '2019-10-01 6:40:00' AND DateTime <= '2019-10-01 16:10:00'
    GROUP BY psb_line

) a
GROUP BY linea
```

Answer (score 2):

Hola amigo no cuento con los detalles de tu tabla.

Pero intenta con esto y vamos viendo.

```
SELECT linea,MAX(B.produccion) AS produccion, COUNT(falla) AS TotalFallas
FROM sisma.registroproblemaaoi A
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT psb_line, SUM(psb_produc) AS produccion 
    FROM psb_smt.psb_produccion
        WHERE DateTime >= '2019-10-01 6:40:00' AND DateTime <= '2019-10-01 16:10:00'
GROUP BY psb_line
) B ON B.psb_line=A.linea
WHERE fecha='2019-10-01' AND hora >='6:40' AND hora <='16:10' 
GROUP BY linea
```

Hacemos un JOIN con la query que me muestras y luego igualmos los valores en este caso uso LEFT pero si gustas y no quieres que te traiga null usa un INNER JOIN

Comment: wow muchass gracias, funciona!!

Comment: :D que bien saludos

Comment: Eso funciona siempre y cuando tanto sisma.registroproblemaaoi como psb_smt.psb_produccion tengan los mismos valores en el campo línea.  Si en psb_smt.psb_produccion hay unas líneas que no están en sisma.registroproblemaaoi no se mostrarán en los resultados.